# Factory method combining static and dynamic polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I am working with two corresponding class hierarchies, A and B, where I need to create instances of sub-types of B from instances of matching sub-types of A. I can't find a "clean" way to create B objects from A objects because

1. B objects only have pointers to A objects so a B::factory would not know what kind of B to make as it doesn't know what derived type of A it gets without some sort of ugly `dynamic_cast` that would be hard to maintain as new sub-types of A and B are added to the library.
2. B classes depend on template parameters that A classes do not. It's not obvious how a factory method in A could therefore create a B since A classes have virtual inheritance and such a method would need to be templated, which is not possible.

Example classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct AType {
  virtual void apply( const T*, T* ) const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct ASubType1 : public AType<T> {
  void apply( const T*, T* ) const override;
};

template<typename T>
struct ASubType2 : public AType<T> {
  void apply( const T*, T* ) const override;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class BType {
public:
  BType( const AType<T>* A_in ) : A(A_in) {}

  virtual std::common_type_t<T,U> compute( const U& ) = 0;

  static std::unique<BType> factory( const AType<T>* A_in );
//  if A_in has type ASubType1, return std::make_unique<BSubType1<T,U>>
//  else if A_in has type ASubType2, return std::make_unique<BSubType2<T,U>>
//  else return nullptr

protected:
  auto get_A() const { return A; } // So BSubTypes have access

private:
  AType<T>* A;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class BSubType1 : public BType<T,U> {
public:
  using BType<T,U>::BType;
  std::common_type_t<T,U> compute( const U& ) override;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class BSubType2 : public BType<T,U> {
public:
  using BType<T,U>::BType;
  std::common_type_t<T,U> compute( const U& ) override;
};
```

It seems like there ought to be some sort of clever Vistor-based solution to generating the correct B objects from their corresponding A, however, the only solution besides `dynamic_cast`
that I have found is to add a method to the A classes that can return an `enum` corresponding to each A sub-type and have B::factory take this `enum` as an argument to return the correct sub-type of B. This approach is not particularly satisfying as it requires intrusively changing type information in a base class, where it would be desirable to add new classes to the A and B families without having to touch any existing classes.

Is there a more elegant approach, such as one using visitors, than what I am currently doing?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, so I'm not sure about an answer. Personally I would split the factory out of the base class. We can write a visitor for translating A Subtypes into B Subtypes and vice versa if you'd like, too. Sorry, I meant to add that I think we should discuss this in a chat if you're up for it.

Comment: Yes, I think having some sort of component that automatically generates B types from A types is what I want. The thing I'm confused about is if this visitor visits A types to create B types, then it must know about template parameter U, which A is agnostic to.

Comment: I'd happily discuss this in chat.

Comment: It seems you need virtual template methods, which doesn't exist. Alternative is a double dispatch (which is not native in C++), but can be done with (limited) know types (visitor pattern).